# I've built a drupal module, now what?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I followed the tutorials and created a simple chess module for Drupal 8. Now I'm wondering how to include the page in the drupal installation. I already included the chess module in the modules folder, and checked chess on the configuration page. But now I'm stuck. How do I get the page returned by the controller to actually show up on a Drupal page? Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom block within your module, then use the Block Layout screen to place that block in the relevant region, you can then adjust the block settings so it only displays on a certain page. So I'd probably just make a basic page, then place the block on it.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-block